# ANTLR4: Lexer.getCharIndex() return value not behaving as expected

Tags: antlr4

I want to extract specific fragment of lexer rule, so I wrote the following rule:

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

root
    : LINE+ EOF
    ;
```

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

@lexer::members {
    private int startIndex = 0;

    private void updateStartIndex() {
        startIndex = getCharIndex();
    }

    private void printNumber() {
        String number = _input.getText(Interval.of(startIndex, getCharIndex() - 1));
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}

LINE:                          {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? ANSWER SPACE {updateStartIndex();} NUMBER {printNumber();} .+? NEWLINE;
OTHER:                         . -> skip;

fragment NUMBER:               [0-9]+;
fragment ANSWER:               '( ' [A-D] ' )';
fragment SPACE:                ' ';
fragment NEWLINE:              '\n';
fragment DOT:                  '.';
```

Execute the following code:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class TestParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromString("( A ) 1. haha\n" +
                "( B ) 12. hahaha\n" );
        Lexer lexer = new TestLexer(charStream);

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        ParseTree parseTree = parser.root();

        System.out.println(parseTree.toStringTree(parser));
    }

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
1
12
(root ( A ) 1. haha\n ( B ) 12. hahaha\n <EOF>)
```

At this point, the value of the fragment **NUMBER** is printed as expected. Then I add the fragment **DOT** to the lexer rule **LINE**:

```
LINE:                          {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? ANSWER SPACE {updateStartIndex();} NUMBER {printNumber();} DOT .+? NEWLINE;
```

The output of the above test code is as follows:

```
1
1
(root ( A ) 1. haha\n ( B ) 12. hahaha\n <EOF>)
```

Why does the second line of output change to 1, this is what I don't understand.

If we modify the test code as follows:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class TestParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromString("( B ) 12. hahaha\n"+
                "( B ) 123. hahaha\n");
        Lexer lexer = new TestLexer(charStream);

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        ParseTree parseTree = parser.root();

        System.out.println(parseTree.toStringTree(parser));
    }

}
```

At this time, when **LINE** does not contain **DOT**, the output is as follows:

```
12
123
(root ( B ) 12. hahaha\n ( B ) 123. hahaha\n <EOF>)
```

When **LINE** contains **DOT**, the output is as follows:

```
12
12
(root ( B ) 12. hahaha\n ( B ) 123. hahaha\n <EOF>)
```

##### Update

I have submitted this issue to GitHub: [Lexer.getCharIndex() return value not behaving as expected · Issue #3606 · antlr/antlr4 · GitHub](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/3606)

Comment: Not a direct answer to why you’re seeing this result, but, as a comment.  Your `LINE` Lexer rule really looks like it should be a parser rule. Then you’d have the Context object to provide all the parts for you.  Is there some reason you are making this a Lexer rule?  Generally, you want to think of tokens being the “atoms” of you grammar, and the parser rules, the “molecules”.  If find your self needing to break tokens apart, maybe they’re not really “atoms”

Comment: @MikeCargal In fact, what is described in the question is just an example, I was hoping to find a convenient way to get the lexer token fragment value, but the code is not working as expected. I know `getText()` can get the text matched by the entire lexer rule, but is there a convenient way to get the fragment value in the lexer rule?

Comment: No, alas, fragments cannot be separately extracted.

Comment: printNumber() is not being called at the end of `[0-9]+`, but after the first char in the pattern. You can work around the problem if you force an action within the NUMBER set itself: unfold NUMBER into LINE with this: `NUMBER => ([0-9] {})+`. Your code (with the action before DOT) will then work fine. This feels like a bug with Antlr.

Comment: @kaby76 After testing, I found that ANTLR uses the offset of the first actual data as the subsequent offset.

Comment: @kaby76 `printNumber()` doesn't seem to be called after the first char in the pattern, but with the actual data, looking at my latest example.

Comment: I implemented the workaround in this [repo](https://github.com/kaby76/so71645433). But, for the grammar without the empty action in LINE, the getCharIndex() value returned in printNumber() is the same difference in size the first time a LINE is found, even if there OTHER tokens are intermingled with LINE tokens. This really seems to be a bug. I'll create an issue for it in github.com/antlr/antlr4.